# Strongloop: Polymorphic HasAndBelongsToMany relation with uuids

Tags: strongloop

I try to use a polymorphic HasAndBelongsToMany relation while using uuids, too. My problem is, that I can't teach Strongloop to use id's with a string as a type instead of a number in the necessary many-to-many-table. This leads to SQL-errors while creating new relations.

Let me explain is with an example:

I have two models: CartCollection and Cart. A collection should have different kind of carts including Cart itself. Cart and CartCollection have uuids instead of simple ids. Defining this as a property in the model-json works so far. The problem is the polymorphic many-to-many-relation between them. I try to use a polymorphic HasAndBelongsToMany relation to realize that. In this table I try to override the id-type as well.

This is my JSON-Code:

```
{
  "name": "SaleCartCollection",
  "plural": "SaleCartCollections",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "id": {
      "type": "string",
      "length": 36,
      "id": true
    }    
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "saleCartsPoly": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model":"SaleCart",
      "polymorphic" : {
        "as": "saleCartsPoly",
        "invert": true
      },
      "through": "SaleCartCartCollectionLink"
    }
  },
  "acls": [],
  "methods": []
}

{
  "name": "SaleCart",
  "plural": "SaleCarts",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "id": {
      "type": "string",
      "length": 36,
      "id": true
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "SaleCartCollections": {
      "type": "hasAndBelongsToMany",
      "model": "SaleCartCollection",
      "polymorphic": {
        "as":"saleCartsPoly",
        "foreignKey" : "saleCartsPolyId",
        "discriminator" : "saleCartsPolyType"
      },
      "through": "SaleCartCartCollectionLink"
    }
  },
  "acls": [],
  "methods": []
}

{
  "name": "SaleCartCartCollectionLink",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "properties": {
    "saleCartsPolyId": {
      "type": "string",
      "length": 36
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
  },
  "acls": [],
  "methods": []
}
```

If I now try to POST a new CartCollection to an existing Cart, I get this output:

```
loopback:connector:mysql SQL: INSERT INTO `SaleCartCartCollectionLink`(`saleCartsPolyId`,`saleCartsPolyType`,`saleCartCollectionId`) VALUES(?,?,?), params: [null,"SaleCart","bad7a6fc-1798-49c5-a0cb-fa59eba5b3a4"] +8ms
loopback:connector:mysql Error: {"code":"ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR","errno":1054,"sqlState":"42S22","index":0} +11ms
```

I found out that this is happening, because Strongloop ignores my property-definition in the Through-model. It is still a number as you can see here in the model-schema in the explorer:

```
[
  {
    "saleCartsPolyId": 0,
    "id": 0,
    "saleCartsPolyType": "",
    "saleCartCollectionId": ""
  }
]
```

Does anyone has an idea if I'm doing something wrong or is it a bug in Strongloop?

Best regards

Niclas

Answer (score 1):

I am a co-worker of Niclas and we solved our problem as follows.

We define

- the "Cart hasMany CartCollection through CartCartCollectionLink" relation polymorphic "as cart"
- the "CartCollection hasMany Cart through CartCartCollectionLink" polymorphic "as cartCollection"
- and here comes the important part: two polymorphic "CartCartCollectionLink belongsTo [Cart | CartCollection]" relations polymorphic " **with polymorphic.idType: string**!

The interesting part is, that the idType property is not set correctly for HasAndBelongsToMany relations.

Someone might want to take a look at relation-definition.js:1566:

```
  if (params.polymorphic) {
    var polymorphic = polymorphicParams(params.polymorphic);
    options.polymorphic = polymorphic; // pass through
    var accessor = params.through.prototype[polymorphic.as];
    if (typeof accessor !== 'function') { // declare once
      // use the name of the polymorphic rel, not modelTo

      // *** you might want to set idType here: ***
      params.through.belongsTo(polymorphic.as, { polymorphic: true });
    }
  }
```

CartCartCollectionLink.json

```
{
  "name": "SaleCartCartCollectionLink",
  "relations": {
    "saleCarts": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "SaleCart",
      "foreignKey": "saleCartId",
      "polymorphic": {
        "as": "saleCart",
        "idType": "string"
      }
    },
    "saleCartCollections": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "SaleCartCollection",
      "foreignKey": "saleCartCollectionId",
      "polymorphic": {
        "as": "saleCartCollection",
        "idType": "string"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Cart.json

```
{
  "name": "SaleCart",
  "properties": {
    "id": {
      "type": "string",
      "length": 36,
      "id": true
    }
  },
  "relations": {
    "saleCartCollections": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "SaleCartCollection",
      "foreignKey": "saleCartId",
      "through": "SaleCartCartCollectionLink",
      "polymorphic": {
        "as": "saleCart"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

CartCollection.json

```
{
  "name": "SaleCartCollection",
  "properties": {
    "id": {
      "type": "string",
      "length": 36,
      "id": true
    }
  },
  "relations": {
    "saleCarts": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "SaleCart",
      "foreignKey": "saleCartCollectionId",
      "through": "SaleCartCartCollectionLink",
      "polymorphic": {
        "as": "saleCartCollection"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, actually based on this one: [link](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/APIC/HasAndBelongsToMany+relations) it should work with hasAndBelongsToMany type. True is I configured this for models on each side, maybe it is supposed to be configured only on single from 2 many-to-many models. Anyway, your suggestion based on js file analysis solved my issue. Thx.